# Why does an HTTP connection call crash my app?

Tags: android, http, httpconnection

When executing `conn.connect();`, my app crashes. This is my code:

```
package com.example.andrejkovict.myapplication;

import ...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String url = "localhost/test.php?tel="+number;
        String ret = HttpGet(url);
        Log.e("tag","http "+ret);
    }


    public String HttpGet(String myUrl) throws IOException
    {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";

        URL url = new URL(myUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        Log.e("tag","http 1");
        conn.connect();
        Log.e("tag","http 2");
        inputStream = conn.getInputStream();

        if(inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Did not work!";
        return result;
    }

    public static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) result += line;
        inputStream.close();
        return result;

    }
}
```

In the console, the only output is: "http 1" and not "http 2" and "http return string"

Where is the problem?

Comment: instad od localhost use ipaddress

Comment: @Chickenturtle Why?

Answer (score 0):

use below code.

```
String urlink = "http://localhost/test.php?tel="+number;
     URL url = new URL(link);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.connect();
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
                String data = "";
                String webPage="";
                while ((data = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    webPage += data + "\n";
                }
```

Comment: same probolem conn.connect(); -> crash

Comment: Use ip address instead of localhost

Comment: This answer would benefit from an explanation as to what it changes and why the change(s) fix OP's problem.